# Magit diff with --name-only?

Tags: magit, git, diff, filenames

I am browsing the differences between two branches of a repository via

```
git diff --name-only branch1 branch2
```

I also use the `--name-status` option sometimes, since I may need to see what sort of difference there is for a given file. Plodding along with plain old `git` will do the job, but there are some obvious deficiencies. The main ones are: no color, no Emacs operations, and you cannot collapse directories. It makes this diff rather cumbersome to work through. Moreover, both branches are large and there are many differences between them.

Does Magit have some sort of diff interface that allows you to use `--name-only` & `--name-status`? I don't see any switches or options for doing this in `*magit-diff-popup*`.

Answer (score 1):

The diff popup doesn't (currently) support `--name-only` or
`--name-status`.  You could add them yourself with
`magit-define-popup-switch` and the output will show, but the buffer
won't be parsed correctly.

You can achieve a similar output by calling
`magit-section-cycle-diffs` (<kbd>M-tab</kbd>), but I'd guess you're
trying to avoid including the diffs at all since you say that there
are many differences between the two branches.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes, unfortunately `M-tab` hasn't helped much because Magit starts choking Emacs when it tries to render the diffs. `M-tab` only helps after the diffs are rendered. Is there a way to get Magit to trigger that function (or something similar) *before* it starts trying to render the diffs?

Comment: You could try setting `magit-diff-expansion-threshold` to a low value.

Comment: Well, I set `magit-diff-expansion-threshold` to `0.1` and the diff still took forever. I don't even know how long it will take since I stopped it after 10-15 minutes. Any other suggestions?